# Make Curved Ends that form into a circle base?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, bevel

So I am trying to figure out how to make this base shape. I've tried array modifier with a circle curve, but that makes my pieces separate and not connected.

[image]

So far I have this simple outline, but not sure how to make the top pieces beveled properly since the angles are not fully straight.

[image]

Is there any easy solution to making these curved tops?

If I extrude and make bevels it looks like this but it's not angle properly and seems incorrect

[image]

Comment: Did you create the thickness with a _Solidify_ modifier or else? Is the top row of faces vertically flat or angled according to the side walls?

Comment: I made a circle with 12 verts then extruded up and extruded inwards then scaled the top face with z to 0 so they stay flat, but those 2 edges are slightly angled so beveling doesn't work for a simple solution

Comment: have u tried using a weld modifier after the array modifier so that they get connected?

Comment: I would remove the inner walls and use a _Solidify_ modifier, this makes it easier. You can apply the _Solidify_ afterwards if you need it as "real" mesh.

Comment: @chris how would the weld modifier connect the pieces made by the array modifier?

Comment: why don't u just try instead of asking back again?

Comment: because that is, what the weld modifier does. It is pretty similar to "merge by distance". So if you have double vertices, the weld modifier will "melt" them to 1 vertex and so you have a connected mesh. You could have easily tried yourself by just using the default cube, array modifier, then apply array modifier ->edit mode _> mesh -> separate loose parts -> you get several objects. Same with an weld modifier -> apply all -> you get one object

Comment: Now I want a muffin or cupcake. So much for my diet. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Delete the inner walls and just keep the outside faces. You can add thickness with a *Solidify* modifier (now or after creating the rounded tops, doesn't matter).

[image: outside walls]

2. Go into an orthographic view from the front or right, whereever you have your reference. Move the top edge further up with <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> and scale it with <kbd>S</kbd> so that it covers the shape you want to achieve.

[image: extend shape]

3. Create a loop cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and slide it up to where the rounded tops should start.

[image: loop cut]

4. Now select the top edge again. From the viewport menu, choose *Mesh > Split > Faces & Edges by Vertices*. You might not see a difference immediately, but each vertex on the top edge is now split in two vertices.

[image: split vertices]

5. While they are all still selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the vertices. Like edge bevel you can scroll the mouse wheel to get more or less segments. Hit <kbd>C</kbd> to clamp the effect so that vertices can't go past each other. Left-click or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

[image: bevel vertices]

6. Now this might look too rounded, so directly after beveling there is the tool options menu on the bottom right. Change the default *Offset* in the *Width Type* dropbox to something else, like *Percent* for example and change the value for width. This looks less rounded.

[image: width type]

7. At last, hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* to get rid of the doubled vertices that might be there because of the clamped bevel.

[image: merge by distance]

If you now add a *Solidify* modifier to the object (or already have one), the result looks like this:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

You could create a 12 vertex cylinder with *Cap Fill Type > Triangle Fan*, remove 11/12 segments:

[image]

Subdivide vertically, move up the top vertice with the *Proportional Editing (Sphere)* activated:

[image]

Create an empty at the same position as the object origin, give your object an *Array* modifier, *Object Offset* mode with the empty as *Object*, rotate the empty 30° on Z:

[image]

Give your object a *Lattice* modifier, scale down the bottom of your lattice, give your object a *Solidify* modifier in order to give it thickness:

[image]

Shade smooth your object, activate the *Auto Smooth* option:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This could be a place for *Simple Deform > Taper*, so you can work in convenient axes.

Staring with a 12-sided topless cylinder:

- Mark all edges with Bevel Weight 1
- Subdivide all with 2 cuts
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> to select every mid- section edge around the top, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> raise to  rough half-circles:

[image]

.. and then you're ready for:

[image]

- *Simple Deform > Taper*
- *Solidify* ('Complex', 'Even', 'None')
- *Bevel*  (by Weight, 2 segments, Shape profile: 1)
- *Subdivision Surface*

[image]